# Batch script - Echo variable with \n

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script variable like this:

```
Set myvar=hello\nworld
```

And when I echo myvar, i get the whole hello\nworld literally. How can I ask it to parse my \n and intrepret it as a new line character, so that I can echo that in two lines?

Comment: you can define a newline variable `\n` and use it then with `set myvar=hello!\n!world`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question really means "How to embed a new line character in a variable?", then this is the answer:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set myvar=hello^

world
echo !myvar!
```

A caret `^` character means take the next character literally, but in this case the "next character" is just a new line, so it is taken literally in the variable and the command continue until the next end of line (as usual), so the `set` command ends after the `world` line. The embedded `<NL>` can only be correctly processed via delayed !expansion!.

The embedded `<NL>` is correctly processed in other cases; for example:

```
for /F %%a in ("!myvar!") do echo %%a
```

Comment: `The embedded <NL> can only be correctly processed via delayed !expansion!.` and in the next line you show how to use it with FOR loop parameters :-)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, there are different programming languages and `\n` doesn't always mean "new line" ;).

`echo hello&echo.world` will do what you want if you want to have it in one line of code. Otherwise, it's

```
echo hello
echo.world
```

In batch `echo.` means new line or if `.` is followed by some text it means echo the text in a new line.

Comment: You should not use `echo.` to leave a blank line; use `echo/` instead. See: [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774): _"Technically, ECHO. is a serious waste of CPU cycles. ...when the script encounters "ECHO." it will not immediately print the blank line, but will first trawl through every directory that is on the %PATH% to see if there is a file called ECHO to execute"_.

Comment: `echo hello&echo.world` are simply two commands. I wouldn't count them as a linefeed. And you can't hold them in a variable